# How to optimize query?

Tags: mysql

I need to select data from one table, but in two steps. I've try to use IN() for that:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE CONCAT(field1,'|',field2) IN 
     (
          SELECT CONCAT(field1,'|',field2) 
          FROM my_table WHERE field3=12345 AND field4=0
     )
```

But it working very slowly. How to implement it correctly?

Update: firstly I need to select from my_table all rows which qualify condition 'field3=12345 AND field4=0'. Secondly I need to select all rows with the same field1 and field2.

Comment: Is `field3` and `field4` indexed? Is your data normalised? Remove the sub-query and join the tables?

Comment: I assume you replaced your real table name with `my_table`.  Are you really using the same table in the from statement and in the nested select?  Because... all that isn't necessary, then.  If they're two different tables, I could understand.

Comment: Why on Earth are you doing this `CONCAT` operation?  Am I missing something, or is this going to return the same results as: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE field3=12345 AND field4=0` ?

Comment: I update the question and add explanation.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ. no, it doesn't indexed. How to join tables correctly in this case?

Comment: @gloomy.penguin, You are right, I've try to use the same table. I need to get data from this table and then make search with this data.

Comment: @David, that is not same. Subquery searching by field3 and field4. And query searching by field1 and field2.

Comment: @BArtWell: You sure about that?  You're basically querying: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE X IN (SELECT X FROM Table WHERE Y=Z)`  Logically, that's the same as `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Y=Z`  The outer query isn't filtering on anything.  Consider it in real-world terms... "Show me all people named Bob in the set of all people named Bob with Brown hair" is the same as "Show me all people named Bob with Brown hair".

Comment: @David, But X doesn't relate to Y. It looks like "Show me all people with color of hair same as Bob's hair color" where I know only name - Bob.

Comment: @BArtWell: Is this query correctly producing that result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62975/discussion-between-bartwell-and-david).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple conditions in JOIN so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table mt
JOIN 
     (
          SELECT DISTINCT field1,,field2
          FROM my_table WHERE field3=12345 AND field4=0
     ) AS q
ON mt.field1 = q.field1 AND mt.field2 = q.field2;
```

The subquery needs `DISTINCT` so we won't have doubles in the result.

Answer (score 1):

with your person example...

```
create table person (
   person_id int primary key,
   person_name varchar(20), 
   person_hair varchar(20) 
);

insert into person values (1,'bob','brown'); 
insert into person values (2,'jim','brown'); 
insert into person values (3,'travis','blonde'); 
insert into person values (4,'ron','red'); 

mysql> select * from person where person_name='bob' and person_hair='brown';
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| person_id | person_name | person_hair |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|         1 | bob         | brown       |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from person where person_name='bob' or  person_hair='brown';
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| person_id | person_name | person_hair |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|         1 | bob         | brown       |
|         2 | jim         | brown       |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select   *
    -> from     person as p1
    -> where    p1.person_hair in (select  person_hair
    ->                             from    person
    ->                             where   person_name='bob');
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| person_id | person_name | person_hair |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|         1 | bob         | brown       |
|         2 | jim         | brown       |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: You are right. When we are searching by 1 parameter (like a hair color), we just need to use IN() operator. But when here is 2 parameters or more...

Comment: two parameters or two return values

Comment: (i know you've already got your answer but i had already typed it up. i'm still not sure i even fully understand the situation... and you really should try not to join on string fields.  use ID's if you can)

Comment: Two fields in result of subquery. Please, look for the Jakub Kania answer. It working well.
Unfortunately I cannot use ID's here. If you are interested, contact with me and I will try to explain the situation. And thank you for answer.